# JavaScript bookmarklet to delete all cookies within a given domain

Tags: javascript, cookies, bookmarklet

I am testing a web app that writes cookies to subdomain.thisdomain.com and several subfolders within that. I'm looking for JavaScript that I can put into a bookmarklet that will delete all cookies under that subdomain, regardless of the folder in which they exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Very good for create a cookieless subdomain (I mean very good to serve static resources according to Google guidelines: http://code.google.com/intl/fr/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clearing all cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Derived from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript#179514):

```
javascript:new function(){var c=document.cookie.split(";");for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){var e=c[i].indexOf("=");var n=e>-1?c[i].substr(0,e):c[i];document.cookie=n+"=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";}}(); return void(0);
```

Due to browser security issues, this will only work when executed while on a page that has access to all the cookies you want to delete.

Comment: Is there a place to put the domain name in this JavaScript? I'd like to remove cookies within my own browser for a particular domain and all subdomains. Like "www.microsoft.com" would take anything that starts with "www.microsoft.com" and remove all cookies.

Comment: Bookmarklets play inside the browser's security sandbox, so they're not allowed to edit cookies from a different domain.

Comment: Okay. I didn't read that right. I figured anything running as a bookmarklet would have access to all browser settings.

Comment: Used the JS in a page to remove all cookies for a site. Worked great. Thx!

Comment: What's with the `new function(){}`?

Comment: It creates an anonymous function which ensures that the variables inside it are scoped to be within that function only.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683) extension to Firebug.