# Clearing all cookies with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

How do you delete all the cookies for the current domain using JavaScript?

Comment: Another way to do this (outside of JS) is with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2310591/2578566 - it's PHP based, but an option for those who use PHP.

Answer (score 441, accepted):

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        const cookie = cookies[i];
        const eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        const name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Note that this code has two limitations:

- It will not delete cookies with `HttpOnly` flag set, as the `HttpOnly` flag disables Javascript's access to the cookie.
- It will not delete cookies that have been set with a `Path` value. (This is despite the fact that those cookies will appear in `document.cookie`, but you can't delete it without specifying the same `Path` value with which it was set.)

Comment: Nice one, but after experimenting, I found that a site can have only one cookie without =, and then it is a nameless cookie, you get its value actually.
So if eqPos == 1, you should do `name = ""` instead, to erase the nameless value.

Comment: Beware! If your cookies are configured to use a path or domain component, this handy snippet won't work.

Comment: True. The snippet could be modified to ask you for those details; but this works for most cases.

Comment: How would this be modified to include the path or domain info?

Comment: @Cerin: While it may not have worked for you, it clearly works for a bunch of other people. Perhaps you have to adapt this code for path or domain issues.

Comment: PHP cookie deletion == epic fail. This javascript solution == epic success!

Comment: @Cerin the problem is in his `expires` statement. If you swap in the `eraseCookie()` function from [this source](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), the above function works.

Comment: Didn't investigate why, but my localhost cookies were not cleared. The one by Craig Smedley cleared them, though.

Comment: At least in Chrome cookies are separated by "; ", so we have to `trim()` the additional space or `split('; ')` (by '; ') to make it work properly. I've proposed an edit.

Comment: We need a way to deal with obsolete but highly upvoted answers like this one.

Comment: Not able to delete the cookie for the first time @RobertJ.Walker

Comment: If this doesn't work for you - try putting a `.trim()` at the end of the `var cookie = ` line, and put `;path=/` at the end of the string on the `document.cookie = ` line.

Comment: the comment by @ABPerson about trim and path=/ saves the day! Thank you very much

Answer (score 203):

#### One liner

In case you want to paste it in quickly...

```
document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(c) { document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";path=/"); });
```

And the code for a bookmarklet :

```
javascript:(function(){document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(c) { document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";path=/"); }); })();
```

Comment: Some persistant web sites backup cookies in `localStorage` so `window.localStorage.clear()` may be helpful as well

Comment: The [official answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179514/4829915) comes with 2 limitations, does this answer solve them?

Comment: This isn't clearing cookies in Brave. It is, however, clearing site data which is something I've been looking for. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @LWC no, as far as I know, Javascript can't remove those cookies at all (unless you know the "path" for those with that)

Answer (score 160):

And here's one to clear all cookies in all paths and all variants of the domain (`www.mydomain.example`, `mydomain.example` etc):

```
(function () {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
    for (var c = 0; c < cookies.length; c++) {
        var d = window.location.hostname.split(".");
        while (d.length > 0) {
            var cookieBase = encodeURIComponent(cookies[c].split(";")[0].split("=")[0]) + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; domain=' + d.join('.') + ' ;path=';
            var p = location.pathname.split('/');
            document.cookie = cookieBase + '/';
            while (p.length > 0) {
                document.cookie = cookieBase + p.join('/');
                p.pop();
            };
            d.shift();
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: this should be the best answer

Comment: This one works for me in chrome, while the accepted answer doesn't

Comment: Brilliant! After trying several others which worked on my dev server but not on the production server, this was the first to work on both. Pure gold!

Comment: This also for me works much better than accepted answer. thanks

Comment: Had to add code for domain with leading dot, some of my cookies have it, some don't, even though there are no relevant subdomains. But with those changes, it works well for me, the most complete implementation I've tried so far.

Comment: The [official answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179514/4829915) comes with 2 limitations, does this answer solve them?

Comment: This function affects php sessions, at least in Edge.

Comment: This is not working with latest version of chrome event if the expiration date is set...

Comment: Between this and the answer above, it covered what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Had to add removing the cookies with empty domain and empty path to cover all my cases.

Answer (score 81):

After a bit of frustration with this myself I knocked together this function which will attempt to delete a named cookie from all paths.  Just call this for each of your cookies and you should be closer to deleting every cookie then you were before.

```
function eraseCookieFromAllPaths(name) {
    // This function will attempt to remove a cookie from all paths.
    var pathBits = location.pathname.split('/');
    var pathCurrent = ' path=';

    // do a simple pathless delete first.
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

    for (var i = 0; i < pathBits.length; i++) {
        pathCurrent += ((pathCurrent.substr(-1) != '/') ? '/' : '') + pathBits[i];
        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;' + pathCurrent + ';';
    }
}
```

As always different browsers have different behaviour but this worked for me.
Enjoy.

Comment: @TomHammond, That should be a completely new question.  The primary issues are around the hosted domain vs hosting domain and your ability to control the hosted page.

Comment: This will still not remove httpOnly cookies. They can only be modified over HTTP.

Answer (score 16):

The following code will remove all cookies within the current domain and all trailing subdomains (`www.some.sub.domain.example`, `.some.sub.domain.example`, `.sub.domain.example` and so on.).

A single line vanilla JS version (I think the only one here without the use of `cookie.split()`):

```js
document.cookie.replace(/(?<=^|;).+?(?=\=|;|$)/g, name => location.hostname.split('.').reverse().reduce(domain => (domain=domain.replace(/^\.?[^.]+/, ''),document.cookie=`${name}=;max-age=0;path=/;domain=${domain}`,domain), location.hostname));
```

This is a readable version of this single line:

```js
document.cookie.replace(
  /(?<=^|;).+?(?=\=|;|$)/g,
  name => location.hostname
    .split(/\.(?=[^\.]+\.)/)
    .reduceRight((acc, val, i, arr) => i ? arr[i]='.'+val+acc : (arr[i]='', arr), '')
    .map(domain => document.cookie=`${name}=;max-age=0;path=/;domain=${domain}`)
);
```

Comment: Only solution here that worked for me (including google analytics cookies)! Thank you very much.

Comment: This works on chrome but produces and error on iOS and safari, "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name"

Comment: Watch out with this one! As Mike said, this breaks on iOS and produced a lot of issues for me.

Answer (score 13):

An answer influenced by both second answer here and W3Schools

```
document.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(c) {
  document.cookie = c.trim().split('=')[0] + '=;' + 'expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
});
```

Seems to be working

edit: wow almost exactly the same as Zach's interesting how Stack Overflow put them next to each other.

edit: nvm that was temporary apparently

Answer (score 13):

If you are concerned about clearing cookies only on a secured origin you can use the [Cookie Store API](https://wicg.github.io/cookie-store/) and it's [.delete()](https://wicg.github.io/cookie-store/#CookieStore-delete) method.

```js
cookieStore.getAll().then(cookies => cookies.forEach(cookie => {
    console.log('Cookie deleted:', cookie);
    cookieStore.delete(cookie.name);
}));
```

Visit the [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=cookiestore) table for the [Cookie Store API](https://wicg.github.io/cookie-store/) to check for **browser support**.

Comment: please note that as of today this works only on latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Something may have changed, I had to do this: `cookieStore.delete(cookie)` if I gave it just the `cookie.name` it didn't work, but it works if I gave the object. For example here is how to clear all cookies: `cookieStore.getAll().then(p => p.forEach(c => cookieStore.delete(c)))`

Answer (score 12):

If you have access to the [jquery.cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) plugin, you can erase all cookies this way:

```
for (var it in $.cookie()) $.removeCookie(it);
```

Comment: I just tried it on my own website, which deleted all cookies. Could @Cerin sama try executing the following code in the console before and after clearing cookies? "for (var it in $.cookie()) console.log(it);"

Comment: jichi did you include the jquery library along side with jquery.cookie plugin?

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know there's no way to do a blanket delete of any cookie set on the domain. You can clear a cookie if you know the name and if the script is on the same domain as the cookie.

You can set the value to empty and the expiration date to somewhere in the past:

```
var mydate = new Date();
mydate.setTime(mydate.getTime() - 1);
document.cookie = "username=; expires=" + mydate.toGMTString();
```

There's an [excellent article here](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-and-cookies/) on manipulating cookies using javascript.

Comment: You can also just do `document.cookie="username;expires=" + new Date(0).toGMTString()` - not much difference if the cookie expires 1 second ago or in 1970

Comment: It will not delete cookies that have been set with a `Path` value.

Answer (score 7):

Simpler. Faster.

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
 var c = document.cookie.split("; ");
 for (i in c) 
  document.cookie =/^[^=]+/.exec(c[i])[0]+"=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";    
}
```

Comment: Doesn't handle paths.

Answer (score 5):

```
document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(c) { 
    document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";path=/"); 
});
//clearing local storage
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: thanks for your valid information. I appreciate it

Comment: It will not delete cookies that have been set with a `Path` value.

Answer (score 4):

Figured I'd share this method for clearing cookies. Perhaps it may be helpful for someone else at some point.

```
var cookie = document.cookie.split(';');

for (var i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {

    var chip = cookie[i],
        entry = chip.split("="),
        name = entry[0];

    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

Comment: It will not delete cookies that have been set with a `Path` value.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why the first voted answer doesn't work for me.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595228/how-can-i-delete-all-cookies-with-javascript) said:

> There is no 100% solution to delete browser cookies.
>
> The problem is that cookies are uniquely identified by not just by their key "name" but also their "domain" and "path".
>
> Without knowing the "domain" and "path" of a cookie, you cannot reliably delete it. This information is not available through JavaScript's document.cookie. It's not available through the HTTP Cookie header either!

So my idea is to add a Cookie version control with the full set of setting, getting, removing of cookies:

```
var cookie_version_control = '---2018/5/11';

function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name+cookie_version_control + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name+cookie_version_control + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function removeCookie(name) {   
    document.cookie = name+cookie_version_control+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
}
```

Comment: this saved me hours . deserves the upvote.  `` let now = new Date(0);`` ``let expireTime = now.getTime();`` ``now.setTime(expireTime);`` ``document.cookie =document.cookie+';expires='+now.toUTCString()+';path=/'; `` will get the cookies removed .

Answer (score 4):

I have some more sophisticated and OOP-oriented cookie control module. It also contains `deleteAll` method to clear all existing cookie. Make notice that this version of `deleteAll` method has setting `path=/` that causes deleting of all cookies within current domain. If you need to delete cookies only from some scope you will have to upgrade this method my adding dynamic `path` parameter to this method.

There is main `Cookie` class:

```
import {Setter} from './Setter';

export class Cookie {
    /**
     * @param {string} key
     * @return {string|undefined}
     */
    static get(key) {
        key = key.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1');

        const regExp = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + key + '=([^;]*)');
        const matches = document.cookie.match(regExp);

        return matches
            ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1])
            : undefined;
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} name
     */
    static delete(name) {
        this.set(name, '', { expires: -1 });
    }

    static deleteAll() {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');

        for (let cookie of cookies) {
            const index = cookie.indexOf('=');

            const name = ~index
                ? cookie.substr(0, index)
                : cookie;

            document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} name
     * @param {string|boolean} value
     * @param {{expires?:Date|string|number,path?:string,domain?:string,secure?:boolean}} opts
     */
    static set(name, value, opts = {}) {
        Setter.set(name, value, opts);
    }
}
```

Cookie setter method (`Cookie.set`) is rather complex so I decomposed it into other class. There is code of this one:

```
export class Setter {
    /**
     * @param {string} name
     * @param {string|boolean} value
     * @param {{expires?:Date|string|number,path?:string,domain?:string,secure?:boolean}} opts
     */
    static set(name, value, opts = {}) {
        value = Setter.prepareValue(value);
        opts = Setter.prepareOpts(opts);

        let updatedCookie = name + '=' + value;

        for (let i in opts) {
            if (!opts.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

            updatedCookie += '; ' + i;

            const value = opts[i];

            if (value !== true)
                updatedCookie += '=' + value;
        }

        document.cookie = updatedCookie;
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} value
     * @return {string}
     * @private
     */
    static prepareValue(value) {
        return encodeURIComponent(value);
    }

    /**
     * @param {{expires?:Date|string|number,path?:string,domain?:string,secure?:boolean}} opts
     * @private
     */
    static prepareOpts(opts = {}) {
        opts = Object.assign({}, opts);

        let {expires} = opts;

        if (typeof expires == 'number' && expires) {
            const date = new Date();

            date.setTime(date.getTime() + expires * 1000);

            expires = opts.expires = date;
        }

        if (expires && expires.toUTCString)
            opts.expires = expires.toUTCString();

        return opts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Delete all cookies
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + '=;' +
            'expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;' +
            'path=' + '/;' +
            'domain=' + window.location.host + ';' +
            'secure=;';
    }
}
```

Comment: It will not delete cookies that have been set with a `Path` value.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple code to [delete all cookies in JavaScript](http://mycodingtricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-cookies/#Delete_All_Cookies).

```
function deleteAllCookies(){
   var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
   for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
     deleteCookie(cookies[i].split("=")[0]);
}

function setCookie(name, value, expirydays) {
 var d = new Date();
 d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expirydays*24*60*60*1000));
 var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
 document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; " + expires;
}

function deleteCookie(name){
  setCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Run the function `deleteAllCookies()` to clear all cookies.

Comment: It will not delete cookies that have been set with a `Path` value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm contributing here because this function will allow you to delete all cookies (matching the path, by default no-path or `\`) **also cookies that were set to be included on subdomains**

```
function clearCookies( wildcardDomain=false, primaryDomain=true, path=null ){
  pathSegment = path ? '; path=' + path : ''
  expSegment = "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
  document.cookie.split(';').forEach(
    function(c) { 
      primaryDomain && (document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, expSegment + pathSegment))
      wildcardDomain && (document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, expSegment + pathSegment + '; domain=' + document.domain))
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list by looking into the document.cookie variable. Clearing them all is just a matter of looping over all of them and clearing them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

#### Functional Approach + ES6

```
const cookieCleaner = () => {
  return document.cookie.split(";").reduce(function (acc, cookie) {
    const eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
    const cleanCookie = `${cookie.substr(0, eqPos)}=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;`;
    return `${acc}${cleanCookie}`;
  }, "");
}
```

> Note: Doesn't handle paths

Answer (score 1):

Several answers here do not resolve the path question. I believe that: if you control the site, or part of it, you should know all the paths used. So you just have to have it delete all cookies from all paths used.
Because my site already has jquery (and out of laziness) I decided to use the jquery cookie, but you can easily adapt it to pure javascript based on the other answers.

In this example I remove three specific paths that were being used by the ecommerce platform.

```
let mainURL = getMainURL().toLowerCase().replace('www.', '').replace('.com.br', '.com'); // i am a brazilian guy
let cookies = $.cookie();
for(key in cookies){
    // default remove
    $.removeCookie(key, {
        path:'/'
    });
    // remove without www
    $.removeCookie(key, {
        domain: mainURL,
        path: '/'
    });
    // remove with www
    $.removeCookie(key, {
        domain: 'www.' + mainURL,
        path: '/'
    });
};

// get-main-url.js v1
function getMainURL(url = window.location.href){
    url = url.replace(/.+?\/\//, ''); // remove protocol
    url = url.replace(/(\#|\?|\/)(.+)?/, ''); // remove parameters and paths
    // remove subdomain
    if( url.split('.').length === 3 ){
        url = url.split('.');
        url.shift();
        url = url.join('.');
    };
    return url;
};
```

I changed the .com site to .com.br because my site is multi domain and multi lingual

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```js
function deleteCookie(name) {
  document.cookie = 
    `${name}=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; Path=/`;

    // Remove it from local storage too
    window.localStorage.removeItem(name);
}

function deleteAllCookies() {
  const cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");

  cookies.forEach((cookie) => {
    const name = cookie.split("=").shift();
    this.deleteCookie(name);
  });

  // Some sites backup cookies in `localStorage`
  window.localStorage.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery:**

```
var cookies = $.cookie();
for(var cookie in cookies) {
$.removeCookie(cookie);
}
```

**vanilla JS**

```
function clearListCookies()
{   
 var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
 for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
  {   
    var spcook =  cookies[i].split("=");
    deleteCookie(spcook[0]);
  }
  function deleteCookie(cookiename)
   {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
    var expires = ";expires="+d;
    var name=cookiename;
    //alert(name);
    var value="";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/acc/html";                    
}
window.location = ""; // TO REFRESH THE PAGE
}
```

Comment: This requires jQuery Cookie plugin. jQuery library doesn't have cookie() function.

Comment: And it will not delete cookies that have been set with a `Path` value.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use `js-cookie` npm package and remove cookies by name:

```
import cookie from 'js-cookie'

export const removeAllCookiesByName = (cookieName: string) => {
  const hostParts = location.host.split('.')
  const domains = hostParts.reduce(
    (acc: string[], current, index) => [
      ...acc,
      hostParts.slice(index).join('.'),
    ],
    []
  )
  domains.forEach((domain) => cookie.remove(cookieName, { domain }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it like so:

```
deleteAllCookies=()=>
      {
      let c=document.cookie.split(';')
      for(const k of c)
         {
         let s=k.split('=')
         document.cookie=s[0].trim()+'=;expires=Fri, 20 Aug 2021 00:00:00 UTC'
         }
      }
```

Usage:

```
deleteAllCookies()
```

- the expiration date was a random day prior to this answer; it can be any date before the current day
- In JS you cannot read through cookies based on path
- In JS you can only set or get cookies

Answer (score 0):

This is variation of one of the answers above. If argument (cookieName) is passed, the function removes this given cookie in all subdomains and higher level domains (except TLD). If no argument is passed function deletes all cookies in all domains (except TLD).

```
deleteCookie = function(cookieName) {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
            for (var c = 0; c < cookies.length; c++) {
                var d = window.location.hostname.split(".");
                while (d.length > 1) {
                    if (cookieName) {
                        var cookie = cookieName;
                        c = cookies.length;
                    } else {
                        var cookie = cookies[c].split(";")[0].split("=")[0];
                    }
                    var cookieBase = encodeURIComponent(cookie) + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; domain=' + d.join('.') + ' ;path=';
                    var p = location.pathname.split('/');
                    document.cookie = cookieBase + '/';
                    while (p.length > 0) {
                        document.cookie = cookieBase + p.join('/');
                        p.pop();
                    };
                    d.shift();
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a problem in IE and Edge. Webkit browsers (Chrome, safari) seem to be more forgiving. When setting cookies, always set the "path" to something, because the default will be the page that set the cookie. So if you try to expire it on a different page without specifying the "path", the path won't match and it won't expire. The `document.cookie` value doesn't show the path or expiration for a cookie, so you can't derive where the cookie was set by looking at the value.

If you need to expire cookies from different pages, save the path of the setting page in the cookie value so you can pull it out later or always append `"; path=/;"` to the cookie value. Then it will expire from any page.

Answer (score -1):

After testing almost ever method listed in multiple style of browsers on multiple styles of cookies, I found almost nothing here works even 50%.

Please help correct as needed, but I'm going to throw my 2 cents in here. The following method breaks everything down and basically builds the cookie value string based on both the settings pieces as well as including a step by step build of the path string, starting with `/` of course.

Hope this helps others and I hope any criticism may come in the form of perfecting this method. At first I wanted a simple 1-liner as some others sought, but JS cookies are one of those things not so easily dealt with.

```
;(function() {
    if (!window['deleteAllCookies'] && document['cookie']) {
        window.deleteAllCookies = function(showLog) {
            var arrCookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
                arrPaths = location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '').split('/'), //  remove leading '/' and split any existing paths
                arrTemplate = [ 'expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT', 'path={path}', 'domain=' + window.location.host, 'secure=' ];  //  array of cookie settings in order tested and found most useful in establishing a "delete"
            for (var i in arrCookies) {
                var strCookie = arrCookies[i];
                if (typeof strCookie == 'string' && strCookie.indexOf('=') >= 0) {
                    var strName = strCookie.split('=')[0];  //  the cookie name
                    for (var j=1;j<=arrTemplate.length;j++) {
                        if (document.cookie.indexOf(strName) < 0) break; // if this is true, then the cookie no longer exist
                        else {
                            var strValue = strName + '=; ' + arrTemplate.slice(0, j).join('; ') + ';';  //  made using the temp array of settings, putting it together piece by piece as loop rolls on
                            if (j == 1) document.cookie = strValue;
                            else {
                                for (var k=0;k<=arrPaths.length;k++) {
                                    if (document.cookie.indexOf(strName) < 0) break; // if this is true, then the cookie no longer exist
                                    else {
                                        var strPath = arrPaths.slice(0, k).join('/') + '/'; //  builds path line 
                                        strValue = strValue.replace('{path}', strPath);
                                        document.cookie = strValue;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            showLog && window['console'] && console.info && console.info("\n\tCookies Have Been Deleted!\n\tdocument.cookie = \"" + document.cookie + "\"\n");
            return document.cookie;
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Not working either, or at least not for me... I had to delete the cookies by HTTP.