# deleting cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

This has left me flabbergasted. I have a site opened on my browser (say stack overflow). And from the browser console I am trying to delete the cookie. I am trying two ways as suggested by many guys online:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
```

and the other one as giving an exact cookie name as follows:

```
document.cookie = '_ga=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

After performing any of those two methods, I try enter:

```
document.cookie
```

And I see all the list of cookies with nothing changed. What am I doing wrong and how do I check if the cookie is deleted?

Comment: did you close the browser and open it back up to the page and see if the cookies are there?

Comment: what is the use of programatically deleting if  I have to close the browser, open and verify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to delete cookie from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688491/unable-to-delete-cookie-from-javascript)

Comment: may enter location.reload() -> programmatically