# Javascript clear local data

Tags: javascript, html, caching

Is there a way to clear all of my application's local data with javascript?

I would like to clear:

```
Session Storage
Cookies
Local Storage
Application Cache (html5 spec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you would have to deal with each individually as each browser would implement differently.

```
sessionStorage.clear

localStorage.clear
```

and for cookies there is already a [good answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

You could of course just put these into your own function.

If the application cache is server side you could have an ajax call to a http post that deletes this.

UPDATE:
it is advised against clearing application cache, http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#expiring-application-caches.  What would you be storing there that you would want deleted?

Comment: Application cache is part of html5 spec.  It is all stored locally and I have not found anything talking about deleting it programmatically (plenty about updating and reloading it though).