# Clear all set cookies using JSP

Tags: jsp, cookies

I want to create a JSP that deletes all cookies that apply to the current page (so, if the reset page resides on site is www.dev.example.com it would get all cookies: `www.dev.example.com`, `.dev.example.com`, .`example.com`) and, server-side, remove them all.

What would the code for this be?

Answer (score 0):

Reference to [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), you just need to use the Set-Cookie header in your HTTP response, and set the cookie you want to be cleared to a blank value.Such as

```
Set-Cookie: ssid=
```

Update:
I am not familiar with JSP, so I use PHP and Javascript for example, assume that you don't have [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) property in your cookies.

I use this PHP code to set cookie, you can upload this PHP script to your web server, www.yourserver.com/setcookie.php

```
<?php
setcookie('name', 'li');
?>
```

And I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript) HTML file to clear your cookies, once again, upload this HTML file to your web server, www.yourserver.com/clearcookie.html

```
<script>
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}

deleteAllCookies();
</script>
```

Comment: Right, so I need to first read all the currently set cookies first, then for each one use the Set-Cookie header. And do I need to set a domain for each as well? So what's that function look like? Is there something that does this as a library - iterate over current cookies and unset?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to delete than another alternative is store them as persistant cookie

```
set MaxAge = -1
```

The MaxAge of -1 signals that you want the cookie to persist for the duration of the session. You want to set MaxAge to 0 instead.

```
    A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and 
will be deleted when the Web browser exits. A zero value causes the cookie
to be deleted.
```

Another is

```
Iterate all cookies in servlet/Scriptlet and set all Cookies Value NULL .
```

also one is

```
use javascript code to remove all cookies.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following Code.

```
<body>

<%

    if(request.getParameter("removeCookie") != null){           
        for(Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()){

            if(!cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")){
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                cookie.setValue("");
                cookie.setPath("/");

                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
    }

%>
<form action="#" method="get">

<input type="submit" id="removeCookie" name="removeCookie" value="Remove cookie" >
</form>


</body>
```

Comment: As you answered yourself in your other answer (why are you posting another answer instead of editing the initial one?), the max age of -1 is wrong.

Comment: because this is another answer , in question he ask about do this
and in comment he ask for code so...