# Html button that clears cookies and redirects to an html page

Tags: javascript, html

Ive been looking at different solutions but do any of you guys know the easy way
to writting a multiple button that clears cookies and redirects to a certain page

I've gotten this far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    deleteAllCookies();
});
```

right now I got a link where i just want it to refresh the actual page, clear cookies, and then redirect to another page.

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's impossible to run a process after refresh, you can't know how is page loaded.
But if you want to clear all cookies than redirect to another page,

deleteAllCookies() function derived from [Robert J. Walker answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript#179514),

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}

function clearAndRedirect(link) {
    deleteAllCookies();
    document.location = link;
}


<a href="javascript:clearAndRedirect('start.html')">Start your bacon</a>
```

---

**ANOTHER WAY:**

if you set a unique id or a class for your anchor tag, also you can do that like this way,

```
<a href="#" class="startbacon">Start your bacon</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".startbacon").click(function() {
        deleteAllCookies();
        document.location = "start.html";
    });
});
```

Comment: at first change your link html as `<a href="javascript:clearAndRedirect('start.html')">Start your bacon</a>` and append javascript functions into the your script tags `<script>append here</script>`

Comment: No there is no difference, can I see a live example?

Comment: I would be more than happy to could provide a email adress? im not allow to post this link in here. Because of company policies

Comment: Great work. Seems like its working, I tweaked it a bit its working great.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the page just add:

```
href="javascript:location.reload(true)"
```

to your anchor tag.

Comment: The user is not asking how to reload the current page.

Comment: Actually he is, " i just want it to "refresh the actual page, clear cookies, and then redirect to another page."

Comment: Hvad about the redirect afterwards? :)

Comment: add a window.location.href = "location.html" after the deleteCookies()

Comment: you guys rock! If ur in Copenhagen, il buy guys a beer

Comment: -1. There is a fatal and fundamental flaw in the idea of just issuing this line of code to accomplish what the user wants. This code will result in a never-ending loop.

Comment: the code is simply telling the asker how to refresh a page he can decide for himself how he wants to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since , you want to refresh the whole page will be refreshed with your actual DOM code
Lets say that your button looks like:

```
<a href="#" id="dostuff">Click me</a>
```

From your sample code I am assuming that you are using Jquery

when a user clicks the button a) all the cookies are cleared b)A new cookie is set, it works as a "flag" in order to check if your page is refreshed c)The page is refreshed d) Your code checks the "flag" if is set, clears once more the cookies and redirects.
For my code I am using [a jquery plugin](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html) in order to manipulate cookies easily, I will also use ocanal's function (great stuff :D )

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var test_flag = $.cookie('flag');
    //get cookie
    if (test_flag == "flag_is_set") {
        //if cookie is set clear all cookies once more and redirect

        deleteAllCookies();
        document.location = "myPage.html";
    }

    $("#dostuff").click(function() {
        //if button is clicked
        //clear all cookies
        deleteAllCookies();
        //set a new cookie as flag
        $.cookie('flag':'flag_is_set');
        //refresh page

        document.location.reload();
    });

});​
```