# General questions about cookies and wordpress users

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

My boss is convinced that since moving servers our sales have dropped. He told me today that he spoke to someone who had a similar issue when changing servers/hosts.

This person told my boss that users have cookies set and when you change the servers it also changes the ip which in turn can render checkout and other features useless for these users for up to 30 days; *when the cookies expire*

So the solution would be to create a notice on the site for all users notifying them of this issue and providing a button that clears the users cache if they choose to click it.

So that being said. Is this a possible issue in wordpress/woocommerce? If so.. is there any pre-built solutions? What kind of script would i need to run on click? Will it work on all devices?

Any insight in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. New cookies should be generated when users log back in. Have you observed any issues logging into the customer account section?

Comment: how do i add an option for our users to manually clear their cookies via a button press?

Comment: Yes we did have issues at first but are having problems re-creating them

Comment: Woocommerce has an option to remove customer data from the system tools section. Woocommerce > System Status > Tools. There's an option to clear custom sessions data, which should empty user carts and clear sessions data, which would require them to generate a new cookie. If people are able to log into their accounts without issue, cookies may not be  a problem.

Comment: Just read your last comment. If people can't log in, it could be cookie relate. How comfortable are you with PHP?

Comment: Not great with php. Okay with jquery. Great with html, css, and specific styling frameworks. But not great with logic.

Comment: So if i clear the session data. All users, including logged in ones. Will lose their cart data. And will it also force a log out and force them to log back in?

Comment: if php is the only solution can u explain what i can do and ill have a friend help me with the php and look over this thread with me.

Thanks!

Comment: Clearing sessions data would whip user carts and force people to log in again. You could also probably clear user cookies by setting the woo and wp cookies with an expiration date set in the past by doing something like
<?php setcookie('wp_woocommerce_session_', 1, time() * -30 ); ?>.

Here are the cookies that may need to be expired. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-cookies/

Has the domain for the site changed at all?

Comment: If you want to play it safe though, Woocommerce also has an option to set a site wide notification in the general settings section, so you could put your notice there along with a link to an article showing people how to clear their cookies.

Comment: Theres no way to just provide a button that they can click that will clear their cookies? Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537080/html-button-that-clears-cookies-and-redirects-to-an-html-page

Would that work?

Comment: The site domain has changed but old one still re-directs to new one.

Comment: and that was over a month ago

Comment: Yeah, that should work. JS is probably a little safer than going the PHP route, so that's not a bad idea.

Comment: it did work. Thanks for letting me swap thoughts with you.

Comment: Happy to do it. Glad you got things straightened out.