# Clear all cookie using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is there anyway to clear the cookie using javascript?

First, I need to clearify the problem. Many posts in StackOverflow give [this kind of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript). But it is clearing cookie like setting the value of all the keys to empty string. But I need to erase the keys as well. How can I do that？

PS： I tried `document.cookie = null`, but it does not work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Comment: Doesn't setting the "expire" value for the cookie to a date in the distant past work for you?

Comment: You should [read more about cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to expire the cookie you want to delete, use this javascript:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```