# How to remove session cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

We are trying to clear the cookie details in browser on pressing 'Logout' button with the following code, but the script doesn't remove the session cookie from the browser. But by clearing the session cookies in IE8 browser using developer tool(Tools > Developer Tools >Cache > Clear Session Cookies), the cookies are cleared.

```
<html:link page="/home.do" onclick="logout();">
    <html:img  page="/images/logout.jpg"/>
</html:link>

function logout(){
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");     
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)     {   
  var cookiename =  cookies[i].split("=");       
  var d = new Date();         
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - 4);   
  var expires = ";expires="+d;       
  var value="";       
  document.cookie = cookiename + "=" + value + expires + ";";     
  }
}
```

How to clear the Session cookies from the browser using script?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the cookie? Call `session.invalidate()` would be enough, the cookie will be deleted on browser exit anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing all cookies with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

if it is httpOnly, then you can not delete it, try modify it from server side

Answer (score 0):

from javascript: Not specifying expiring field, also set value to null, and if it is also hostonly, not specifying domain

Answer (score -1):

If it is a 'session' variable you want to clear...

```
unset( $_SESSION['YOUR_SESSION_VARIABLE_NAME'] );
```

This will completely remove this session variable. The title is misleading. The code he shows is not 'session' cookies, they are regular 'cookies'.