# how can we remove cookies on all pages on logout in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

hey i am new to jquery and using mvc3 with jquery.
can anybody tell me how can we clear cookies on all pages from our website on clicking logout button using jquery?

on login button, my code is:

```
$('.login').click(function(){
    var username = $('#uname').val();
    var password = $('#upass').val();

    $.cookie('username', username, { path: '/' });
    $.cookie('password', password, { path: '/' });
});
```

i want to clear all cookies in one line code with jquery. can anybody suggest me,how can i do that????

Comment: already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript

Comment: Please search the cleanly before posting the question. @alliswell Nice  job.

Comment: @alliswell this code clears the cookies of its document(particular page on which it is created), but i want to delete these cookies from all pages.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a cookie with JQuery, set the value to null:

```
$.cookie('username', null);
$.cookie('password', null);
```

Comment: hey, but i want to delete both cookies with one line code. how can i do that?

Comment: @Parasignals you have to delete the <new line> character