# ClearCookiesAsync() on Cordova

Tags: c#, cookies, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to use a plugin in wp8 cordova to clear the WebBrowser cookies. I already have it communicating with JavaScript and I have something like this in my c# file:

```
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands
{
    public class Clear : BaseCommand
    {
        public void clear(string options)
        {
            // all JS callable plugin methods MUST have this signature!
            // public, returning void, 1 argument that is a string
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("working..");
        }
    }
}
```

And I searched now to clear cookies in wp8, and we call the method [ClearCookiesAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). How I call that method on my clear() function on that code?

Best regards,
Pedro

Comment: Not really an answer to your issue, but would it be possible to do it with JavaScript seeing as you are using Cordova. [JavaScript clear cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Comment: @steveniseki on Cordova apps, document.cookie is not used, so related solutions does not work

Comment: @pedroh Any update about this issue? have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958766/how-do-i-clear-the-cache-of-cordova-web-view-on-windows-phone-8