# How do I clear the cache of Cordova Web View on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: caching, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Cordova 2.9.0 app for Windows Phone 8. The app in question utilises external content heavily, using the JS and HTML content that's being served from another source. It all works fine, but the browser component caches heavily.

The only way I have discovered to clear caches is to uninstall-install the app again to take effect. The downside to this is that my localStorage also clears, slowing down my cycles.

I presume the cache can be cleared by writing extra C# into the Cordova template [they serve](http://phonegap.com/install/), which I use by the way.

Comment: One simple solution is to add a unique value to the query string for each resource when you are debugging or want to refresh the cache. For example, just using the current time stamp: /MyAPI.js?ts=126454637. This will cause the browser to see it as new content. Or, change the server to include headers to not cache the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while it was not that critical, I did stumble to a working answer. The [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class does have a suitable method to call: [ClearInternetCacheAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571213%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Since `CordovaBrowser` inherits from `WebBrowser`, it's just a matter of adding one line to `MainPage.xaml.cs` where the C# init of the start page happens:

```
namespace FooBarApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CordovaView.Loaded += CordovaView_Loaded;
            // blammo!
            this.CordovaView.CordovaBrowser.ClearInternetCacheAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Phonegap Cookies Plugin can be found [HERE](https://github.com/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin)
- A simple, lightweight jQuery plugin for reading, writing and `deleting cookies` can be found [HERE](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

I hope it will resolve your problem. Thanks!!

Comment: How does clearing cookies solve the problem of clearing the cache?

Comment: Sorry, this is not exactly answering my questions. First, this doesn't even have code for WP platforms; only iOS and Android. Second, what @WiredPrairie said.

Comment: @progo so shall i delete it or leave it as usual, suggest me if is not the right answer..

Comment: @ImranKhan: I see no harm leaving it here.

Comment: @progo thanks for ur suggestion...i will leave it as usual, sometimes it might be helpful to iOS and android developers