# Cannot logout from facebook in a windows8 phone app using phonegap. how can I solve this?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cordova, windows-phone-8

Hello guys I am implementing logout from facebook functionality  in my windows 8 phone application. By using the given below code I am able to logout from the facebook but when I  again click on the  facebook login button, then it automatically logged in  without asking for the email and password.

```
var redir_url1 = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/logout_success.html";
//redir_url1 is used to redirect it
alert("inside prototype logout");
//store the value of accesstoken locally in finalAccessTokens
var finalAccessToken1 = window.localStorage.getItem("finalAccessTokens");
alert("finalAccessToken1" + finalAccessToken1);
var authorize_url = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1";
//alert("authorize_url" + authorize_url);
authorize_url += "next=" + redir_url1;
 authorize_url += "&access_token=" + finalAccessToken1;
alert("logout url: " + authorize_url);
 resetSession();

showWebPage1(authorize_url);
//call a function to open the webpage
}

function showWebPage1(loc) {
alert("logout loc" + loc);
// var locs=this.loc;

cordova.exec(success1, error1, "InAppBrowser", "ShowInAppBrowser", loc);

}

function success1(e) {

alert("logout success");
//var accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem("finalAccessTokens");
// var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + accessToken;
//localStorage.removeItem(cookies);
//localStorage.removeItem(finalAccessTokens);
// closeAndClearTokenInformation;
//ClearInternetCacheAsync();


alert("After removing access token" +                         `enter code here`window.localStorage.getItem("finalAccessTokens"));
//finalAccessTokens is used to locally store the value of access token
window.localStorage.clear();
alert("success" + JSON.stringify(e));
var successLogout = JSON.stringify(e);

if ((successLogout.indexOf('https://www.facebook.com/home.php') != -1) &&            
(successLogout.indexOf('loadstop') != -1)) {      
    alert("sss in close");
    cordova.exec(null, null, "InAppBrowser", "close", []);

    alert("after the handle is closed.....");
    this.resetSession();
//to reset the session
}


}

function error1() {
alert("err");

}


FBConnect.prototype.resetSession = function () {

alert("session reset");
this.status = "unknown";
this.session = {};

alert("clear access token/////");
this.session.access_token = null;
alert(this.session.access_token);
this.session.expires = new Date().valueOf() - 1000;
this.session.secret = null;
this.session.session_key = null;
this.session.sig = null;
this.session.uid = null;
alert(this.session.uid);
}
```

Comment: You not need logout step by step, only need clear all cookies then reload. Use plugin: https://github.com/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin/tree/2869c4c6011888608846d4455a03f6ed9620c766

Comment: I think this is for android and ios not for windows8.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove WebBrowser cookies after you logout. I am not sure how you can do that using PhoneGap, but in a C#/XAML app you can remove them like this:

```
await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
```

Comment: @user3852962 check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958766/how-do-i-clear-the-cache-of-cordova-web-view-on-windows-phone-8)

Comment: But I want to know  how it will be done by phonegap??