# How remove cookies in cordova 5.1.1

Tags: cordova, cookies, session-cookies, cordova-plugins, crosswalk-project

I am using cordova 5.1.1 with crosswalk, I am looking ways to remove cookies, the nearest option I came across is: com.cordova.plugins.cookiemaster which does not support removing cookies. Other option can be com.triarc.cookies which is somehow does not seems to be working with cordova 5.1.1

Any thought will be greatly appreciated.

Update: Cookies are HTTP only.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is a duplicate question, but I dont mark it because maybe exists a Cordova solution.

The approach in javascript is this:

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Source: [Clearing all cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Del, what if cookies are http only?

Comment: You want to delete only http cookies?

Comment: Ok, I researched and looks like httpOnly cookies can't be accessed via javasciript, so this solution is not valid for your updated question. How are you setting that cookies? are those from your application?

Comment: yes, these are set from Application side. Any way to access them?

Comment: And how are they added? You can't change to non http cookies? Because I really doubt that you can clean those cookies, as they are to be protected and non-modificable

Comment: PHP side is setting these cookies