# Delete cookie created in PHP using javascript action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I created a cookie in PHP:

```
    function set_newuser_cookie() {
      if ( !is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['sitename_newvisitor'])) {
        setcookie( 'sitename_newvisitor', 1, time()+3600*24*365, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
      }
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'set_newuser_cookie');
```

I want to delete this cookie in a javascript file after a click event, like so:

```
$('.tbf-main-logo-image').on('click', function() {
  document.cookie = 'sitename_newvisitor=;expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
});
```

I have been on every stack overflow thread pertaining to this issue and I have tried: adding a path to the cookie, made a `delete_cookie` function, using jQuery `$.removeCookie`. Nothing seems to be working. One thought is that perhaps everytime my header is loading it is recreating the cookie? But no, it  shouldn't because I have an if statement looking for a cookie with that name. Help!

Comment: You should not do this, as it leaves your site open to XSS atacks. Please, read [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/).

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Comment: I moved the creation of the cookie to the JS file and deletion now works.