# How do I remove cookies when the browser is closed? using angular2-cookies

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies, session-cookies

When I close the browser, I want to remove cookies. How can I do this?
i use th bibliotek angular2-cookie.

Answer (score 3):

The `onbeforeunload` event will allow you to run some code before the user leaves the page. Combining that with the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript) will allow you to clear all the cookies when the user tries to leave the page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  deleteAllCookies();
}

function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

In relation to angular 2, if this is a one-off thing, it's totally fine to put it in your `index.html` page as a bottom snippet, because it's not really related to your Angular 2 application. If you want to do it in Angular 2 fashion, you should be able to put this in your `AppComponent`.

```
@HostListener('window:onbeforeunload', ['$event'])
onBeforeUnload() {
    this.deleteAllCookies();
}

deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank's, there is some things else. how to make an only secure connections?

Comment: What do you mean? That sounds unrelated to this question, maybe you should try asking a new question, or searching SO for the answer.

Comment: @rachedbch, also, it's good form on Stack Overflow to accept an answer, to say it's the correct one, to help out other people who find this question in the future.

Comment: Adam, thank's for the answer. This is what i search.