# Deleting a cookie with no name

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cookies, sharethis

Sharethis wrote a cookie with no name (value "**sharethis_cookie_test**") to my website and it's causing a lot of session problems for me (on Chrome). I've removed the sharethis plugin from my site, but the cookie will still be on users' machines.

`document.cookie` prints out `"__sharethis_cookie_test__; sessionid=kb0akjqdu..."`

How do I remove a cookie with no name? When I try to expire the cookie via

`document.cookie = "__sharethis_cookie_test__=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";`

... it doesn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: This looks right to me...

Comment: Thanks Anil, were you able to test/repro in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

To delete a cookie that has "no name". Try this:

```
document.cookie = '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

Notice that there is no "name" in front of the `=`

Comment: Hey gforce, thanks for the suggestion. Tried it and it doesn't work. I'm also trying to rebuild the cookie list without the bad one (no name)... then trying to set it en masse, `document.cookie = newCookieString`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: weird. I set a cookie with no name in chrome and then removed it that way. Maybe try the method in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript

Comment: it is weird... my own tests to add a no name cookie and delete it worked fine, but deleting the sharethis cookie wouldn't work. I ended up removing sharethis plugin altogether