# Remove the Identity Server Cookie in Browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, identityserver3, httpcookie

I'm using Identity Server for Single Sign On, I would like to delete the Identity Server Cookie manually using JavaScript from an appropriate Client application.

I referred lots of tutorials but no one is given any solution for my requirement.

I deployed my Identity Server in the https://localhost:2025 and I deployed the Client UI in http://localhost:3000

I need to Remove the following Cookie which is displayed under https://localhost:2025 in the following image.

[image]

I tried lots of Stack overflow questions, out of those I listed few for your reference.

[Clearing all cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Comment: You can't touch Http cookies in javascript - you can't even see them in javascript - they can only be cleared by the server - that's why they are called Http cookies

Comment: @JaromandaX - But If I use the `Ctrl + Shift + Del` is deleting the Cookies...

Comment: what is "the Ctrl + Shift + Del" - and how is it related to code in the "Client application"

Comment: oh, "ctrl + shift + Del" is a browser function, not a web page accessible function - you need to understand that a web page does not have the same access to everything that the browser does - it's called "security"

Comment: @JaromandaX - Thanks for your assistance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the cookie was issued with the [`HttpOnly` flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) from the server you will not be able to access or modify its value from the client:

> An HttpOnly cookie cannot be accessed by client-side APIs, such as
>   JavaScript. This restriction eliminates the threat of cookie theft via
>   cross-site scripting (XSS). However, the cookie remains vulnerable to
>   cross-site tracing (XST) and cross-site request forgery (XSRF)
>   attacks. A cookie is given this characteristic by adding the HttpOnly
>   flag to the cookie.

From the provided screenshot it seems that you can only access the `idsvr.session` cookie from javascript because it is not marked as HTTP.

As a workaround you could make an AJAX call to some server side endpoint that will clear all cookies as it will have access to them.

Comment: Could you please assist me how to delete the `idsvr.session`. Because I tried the above said approach but nothing was deleted.

Comment: Try this: `document.cookie = 'idsvr.session=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;'`. Once this code is executed don't forget to reload the page for the changes to reflect in the Chrome developer toolbar.