# clear cookies of a website using devtools console

Tags: javascript, web

We can delete localstorage or sessionstorage using js clear() like

```
localStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.clear()
```

Is there no **cookies.clear()** like this? How? (No chrome extension please)

The quickest I found to clear, clicking on secure icon near website in address bar > cookies > Remove.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/179355/10022239

Comment: Why there is no easy way like the other two above mentioned? I want to know the reason. There may be some limitations why no predefined function is there.

Comment: Cookies are all stored as one string. They are hard to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some code that I found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27374365/10022239

```
 document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(c) { document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";path=/"); });
```

You may also be able to use `cookies.remove();`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/remove