# Please use login or trySilentLogin before logging out ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, google-signin, ionic5

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus
npm install @ionic-native/google-plus
```

This plugin I used and everything works file login and logout in normal scenario but when I do login with google then close the app then logout gives an error

> Please use login or trySilentLogin before logging out

and because of the above error ( i guess ) when I do login with google again then no popup comes as it was not logged out properly.

I cleared cookie too from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript/179514#179514). But it didn't work.

```
login(){
     this.googlePlus.login({})
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }

    logout(){
    this.googlePlus.logout({})
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you found any solution?

Comment: You need to handle catch block for  this.googlePlus.logout({}) then there you do trySilentLogin then inside that logout function again  read this https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/300