# How can i delete all session cookie from my react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, backend

I am doing a project in react right now. I want to figure out a way where i could logout the user out by removing all of the session cookies in my react app.

But i do not know a solution for it. Is it possible to remove all of the cookies at the same time?

Comment: Depends on the kind of cookie. *HttpOnly* and/or *Path* may prevent you meddling from Javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clearing all cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Answer (score -3):

This is not related to React in any way, just JavaScript.

You can delete all cookies by executing:

```js
document.cookie = '';
```

**BUT** this only works for cookies available on the client side (so not ones that are `HttpOnly`). It's very uncommon that session cookies from an authentication server are accessible client side, for security reasons.

In this case: you can't directly, but you need to implement a request to a logout endpoint (if any).