# Restore a session with cookies from another browser with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, developer-tools

Let's say I am logged in (with login/password) on a website/service https://example.com in a browser. If I open `Developer tools`, I can run `document.cookie` in the console and copy the string containing *all the cookies* associated with the current website.

Then I open a new incognito window, I go to https://example.com. Of course, I'm not logged in. I can remove the current cookies with the method described in [Clearing all cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript/33366171#33366171) in the `Developer tools` console, and then restore the cookies copied before:

```
document.cookie = "<the string that I copied before>"
```

Then after a page reload (F5), I expected to be logged-in again, but it did not work. The cookies set with `document.cookie = "<the string that I copied before>"` are not kept. (For example, in the case of Reddit, it did not work.)

What's wrong with this JS approach to set cookies in the "Developer tools" from a previous session from another browser? Shouldn't it work?

Comment: _“I can run document.cookie in the console and copy the string containing all the cookies associated to the current website.”_ - no, not _all_ of them. Only those, that are accessible to client-side JavaScript in the first place. (Keyword: `httpOnly`)

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, I think this is the answer. So there is no way to restore full cookies / a logged-in session into another browser / or into an incognito window of the same browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the session id is set to server only, you can not get session id in JS/console.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Restrict_access_to_cookies

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For completeness/future reference, can you add a source / link?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies, you can find the anwser in section "Restrict access to cookies"