# Deleting all cookies with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

`document.cookie` won't become empty whatever I do, like it does when I clean it using the browser. How would I delete all cookies in JavaScript?

What I tried:

- document.cookie = ""; but cookies behave differently.
- 20~ of results in a search.

Comment: You can handle only cookies set by the current domain the JS is running.

Comment: [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Comment: I said I searched A LOT, it doesn't work at all.