# How YouTube store user data when logout-ed

Tags: javascript, youtube

How does YouTube store user data like recommendations? I'm not logged in, Tried removing `localStorage`, `cookie`, `cache`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F12 -> Application -> Storage -> Clear site data

Make sure that the following options are checked：

- including third-party cookies
- Unregister service workers
- local and session storage
- Indexed DB
- Web SQL
- Cookies
- Cache sotrage

Answer (score 0):

You may not remove the cookies properly. Try to install a plugins called Cookie AutoDelet for your browser.

Comment: I did `document.cookie = ''`

Comment: Plz take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript you have to create a loop to remove the cookies using JS, otherwise you need to remove them one by one

Comment: Looks like YouTube's using cookies - but when I remove it, the cookie restore.