# How to delete all cookies with jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clearing all cookies with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript)

I would like to have a checkbox assigned to activate and wipe out all cookies previously stored in my forms in one go. How would I do that with jquery cookie plugin? I can't seem to find examples in Klaus site and here.

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this question is not a duplicate as the other is specific to plain javascript and this one is specific to jQuery.

Comment: Agreed.  The whole purpose of jquery is to avoid writing boilerplate javascript.   The correct answer to this is: `for (var it in $.cookie()) $.removeCookie(it);`  But I can't post it because this has been flagged as a dup.  (Requires jquery-cookie.)

Comment: Also, the accepted answer does not account for the path being set on the cookie.  Another reason to use a library instead of writing raw js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178263/javascript-bookmarklet-to-delete-all-cookies-within-a-given-domain) should accomplish what you're after:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for(var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var equals = cookies[i].indexOf("=");
    var name = equals > -1 ? cookies[i].substr(0, equals) : cookies[i];
    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
}
```

(code is expanded for clarity from the linked answer, no need to reinvent the wheel here)

There's no need for a plugin in all cases, sometimes a simple JavaScript snippet will do...jQuery really doesn't help at all here

Comment: Been there before, but was too eager to stay in jquery :) So I guess the answer is no easy way to wipe out cookies with jquery? Gotta grab the closest hand I can get then. Thanks

Comment: jQuery is just a bunch of javascript, don't think of them like you're delegating out to something different...it's all the same stuff.  Wrapping some things in a plugin isn't needed a fair portion of the time, it's usually just equivalent to changing the namespace for what some plugins do.

Comment: You didn't answer the actual question related to jquery, but the link did answer my need for now. Thanks

Comment: This answer does not say how to do it in JQuery

Comment: @KevinDeus - jQuery is just JavaScript, and there are many cases where you don't need jQuery, just plain JavaScript will do.

Comment: @VUELA you can wrap this in a function, nothing prevents you from doing so...jQuery doesn't have anything to help here.

Comment: How can this be modified to work for all paths / domains?

Comment: just something i ran into... you can only remove cookies matching the current domain you're on. for instance if you're on www.google.com you cant remove www.bing.com cookies

Comment: @VUELA it can't - that would be a tremendous be a security hole. Stack Overflow shouldn't be able to alter your bank website's cookies, for example.

Comment: @CraigWayne yes - this is absolutely by design. Again, it would be a huge security hole to allow cross-domain editing of cookies, localStorage, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use jquery for that, only pure javascript:

```
function setCookie(name, value, seconds) {

    if (typeof(seconds) != 'undefined') {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (seconds*1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        var expires = "";
    }

    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

And call with setCookie( cookieName, null, -1);

Comment: but he want to do this using jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I love to see jquery version if any please. But I am always listening to any possible solution. Thanks

Comment: Listen you two, jQuery **is** Javascript.  There is absolutely no reason to want it one way or the other, because they are the same.  jQuery should not be used to do this.