# How to clear session using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing mvc application. I used session in view and controller. 
 First when i select value from dropdown list. selected value is managed in view and controller.
but when I again select value from dropdown list , that time on change event I want to clear session.

below is my code for view

```
@model IEnumerable<StockWatch.DTO.ProductDTO>

@using GridMvc.Html
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    int VendorId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["vendorId"]);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
         <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Custom1.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
   </head>
<body> 

     @if (Model == null)
     {

    <div id="vendorDropdownDiv" class =" row-fluid Span9" style ="margin-bottom :15px">

                   <div class="span6"  >
                           <div class="span4" style="margin-left:35px;" >
                         <label >Vendor</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6" >
                      @Html.DropDownList("VendorId", ViewData["list"] as SelectList, "-- Select vendor --", new { @id = "vendorDropdown", @name = "VendorId" })

                  </div>
                 </div>                              

                 <div class="span11" style="text-align:right">           
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create" id="create"/>
                 <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" style="width:45px;" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("index")    '"/>
           </div>
              </div> 
     }    

  <div id="indexview"></div>

     @if (Model != null)
     {
    <div id="modeldiv" class="span12" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;">
       <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:10px;">
       <div class="listheading span9" style="font-size:22px;">Products</div>

      <div class="createlink span3" style="text-align:right;margin-left:10px;">
       @Html.ActionLink("+ Add Product", "Create")
    </div>
  }     
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {      
        $('#vendorDropdown').change(function () {                  
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

and controller code as below

```
       public ActionResult Index(int VendorId=0)
    {
        if (VendorId == 0)
        {
            VendorId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["vendorId"]);
        }

        VendorService vendorService = new VendorService();
        SelectList SelectList = new SelectList(vendorService.GetAll().OrderBy(t => t.Name), "Id", "Name", VendorId);
        ViewData["list"] = SelectList;

        var Categorylist = new SelectList(new[] { "Dull", "Anodised", "All" });

        ViewData["Categorylist"] = Categorylist;

        if (VendorId != 0 )
        {
            Session["vendorId"] = VendorId;
            ProductService productService = new ProductService();
            var productlist = new List<ProductDTO>();             
            productlist = productService.GetAll().Where(x => x.VendorId == VendorId).ToList();

            return View(productlist );
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

here how to clear `Convert.ToInt32(Session["vendorId"]);` this session using jquery.
thank u in advance

Comment: Create an action `ClearSession` and call it using `$.ajax` or `$.get`.

Comment: Sessions are maintained on server and could not removed on client without sending request to server.  You can make a ajax call and do it.

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470517/delete-all-cookies-with-jquery-and-set-new

Answer (score 3):

Sessions are maintained on server and could not removed on client without sending request to server.

As suggested by Patrick Hofman you can Create an action ClearSession and call it using $.ajax or $.get.

Comment: Did you really copy and paste @Ondipuli's comment as an answer?

Comment: @Josh You can clearly see that i answered 54 mins ago and the comment was added 52 Mins Ago

Comment: And that's what happens when you jump to conclusions without paying attention. I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

As the session is stored server side - not client side, you'll need to instruct the server to destroy it. maing a request to an action method 
could do this -

Create an action method in your mvc site -

```
public class ControllerName
{
 public ActionResult DestroySession()
 {
     Session = null;
 }
}
```

then from the page, call the following javascript code:

```
<script>

$('#clearSessionButton').click(
function() {
    $.ajax('/ControllerName/DestroySession');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

call $ajax or $post method to clear a session

```
     $.post("clearsessionAction",function(data){
        //clear your session 
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an action in your controller that will `clear` and `abandon` the session. You can call that action using jQuery ajax and your session will get cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's maybe late but, I hope this will help you
First of all, you need to be carefully when working with session.
Better way it's to create some class that will be do all work with your session 
After what you will need to create controller which will help you to do all u want from js. You will have something like this:

```
public class SessionManager
{
    public static int VendorId
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["vendorId"]); }
    }

    public static void SetVendorId(int id)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["vendorId"] = id; 
    }

    public static void ClearVendorId()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["vendorId"] = null;
    }
}

public class SessionManagerController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetVendorId()
    {
        return Json(SessionManager.VendorId);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetVendorId(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            SessionManager.SetVendorId(id);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json("false");
        }
        return Json("true");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void ClearVendorId()
    {
        SessionManager.ClearVendorId();
    }
}
```

the way to call this methods from client you can choose by yourself.

and by the way, in your view:

```
 int VendorId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["vendorId"]);
```

you will use:

```
int VendorId = SessionManager.VendorId
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simply use `sessionStorage.clear();` and `localStorage.removeItem(keyname)` or `sessionStorage.removeItem(keyname)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQUERY with ajax as below:

1 - in HTML file use a id tag, for example id="clear_session" .

2 - use "clear_session" click event for start ajax in your js file :

```
var clear_session    = $("#clear_session"); 
clear_session.click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: "do=clear_session",
                complete: function(data){ 

                        // your desired finishing function

                }           
        });     
});
```

3 - use this code in index.php file :

```
if ($_POST['do'] == 'clear_session')
{
    // your desired function
}
```

please reply for more guide.
Saeed Rostami.
IT Engineer in I.R.I
+98 935 516 90 58